# Login data hardcoded in code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a username and password but for testing I have hardcoded a username and password that is in the database.

The passwords are encrypted in the DB

But apparently if I do this:

```cs
public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(LoginModel model)
{     
    var salesAgent = CommerceFramework.ShopAccounts.GetShopAccount(Guid.Parse("3E90BB13-36BA-435D-8ED7-E930A4F8C758"), true);
    model.Password = "EielKrkK4Gh5T95aUfY149YtbaFXEia7dAjTP0IyWaY=";

    if (model.UserName == "info@verploegen.nl")
    {              
        if (model.UserName == "info@verploegen.nl" && model.Password == "EielKrkK4Gh5T95aUfY149YtbaFXEia7dAjTP0IyWaY=")
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);
        }
        if (!ShopApi.UserState.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Profile");
}
```

and I look at

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

password is always null. But this is the correct string for password.

Because this is the xml what will be saved in the DB:

```xml
<FieldsDictionary>
  <field name="Password" type="System.String, mscorlib">
    <string>EielKrkK4Gh5T95aUfY149YtbaFXEia7dAjTP0IyWaY=</string>
  </field>
  <field name="Salt" type="System.String, mscorlib">
    <string>vn73BOyHEIzE/SxFxYrCSA==</string>
  </field>
  <field name="AccountDisplayName" type="Null" />
  <field name="CanOrderProducts" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
  <field name="CanSeePrices" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
  <field name="CanSeeStock" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>true</boolean>
  </field>
  <field name="HasLimitedBudget" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib">
    <boolean>false</boolean>
  </field>
</FieldsDictionary>
```

So how to get the password then?

Thank you

and this is the model:

```cs
//
// Summary:
//     A model to login into the webshop.
public class LoginModel
{
    public LoginModel();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the password.
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
    public virtual System.String Password { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether to remember the user to login him automatically
    //     on the next visit.
    [Display(Name = "Login_RememberMe")]
    public virtual System.Boolean RememberMe { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the username.
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_InvalidField")]
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
    [StringLength(80, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
    [TrimAttribute(new[] { })]
    public virtual System.String UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the view:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@*@model Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Account.V_LoginModel_BalieUser*@
    @model LoginModel
```

```html
<div class="semicolumn">
    <div class="form-holder">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.UserName)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">
                <h4></h4>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So I have one textfield where I fill in the username `info@verploegen.nl` but I set the password hardcoded in the action method, so as you can see.

Comment: How about showing the code for `LoginModel`?

Comment: There's no need to check if `model.UserName == "info@verploegen.nl"` a second time.

Comment: I edit the post.